# Tensor X must be from the same graph as Y

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I know this has been asked quite a bit. However, after browsing through the different posts, I still can't seem to fix my error.

I'm currently building a Recurrent Neural Network in order to do sentiment analysis. In this particular file, I'm defining 2 different types of architectures (one with 0 fully connected layer and another one with 1 fully connected layer), all under different functions, so I can then call something like train(1,....), with 1 corresponding to one of the options.

I know the architectures in general are good because I've tested the code without the functions and everything was working.

However, when I tried to organize the code into functions for the different architectures and for the training, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Tensor("RNN1/rnn/Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32).
```

which is pointing to the line

```
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)
```

I'd be very appreciated if anyone could help me with this!!
Thank you so much for your time!

Full code:

```
(...)

inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="inputs")
labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="labels")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

n_words=4000 
embed_size=300 
embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_words, embed_size), -1, 1))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs_)


def rnn_0_fc_layers(inputs_, lstm_size=226, lstm_layers=2, batch_size=600):
    with tf.name_scope("RNN1"): 
        def lstm_cell():
            lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
            return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for i in range(lstm_layers)])

        initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)

        pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:,-1], 1, activation_func=tf.nn.relu)


    return pred, cell, initial_state, final_state    


def rnn_1_fc_layers(inputs_, lstm_size=226, lstm_layers=2, batch_size=600):
    with tf.name_scope("RNN1"): 
        def lstm_cell():
            lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
            return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for i in range(lstm_layers)])

        initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)

        dense1= tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs[:, -1], 256, activation_func=tf.nn.relu)
        dense1 = tf.contrib.layers.dropout(dense1, keep_prob)

        pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dense1, 1, activation_func=tf.nn.relu)

    return pred, cell, initial_state, final_state

def get_batch(x, y, batch_size):
    '''Create the batches for the training and validation data'''
    n_batches = len(x)//batch_size
    x, y = x[:n_batches*batch_size], y[:n_batches*batch_size]
    for ii in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
        yield x[ii:ii+batch_size], y[ii:ii+batch_size]

tf.reset_default_graph()


def train_rnn(model, learning_rate, epochs, batch_size):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    learning_rate= learning_rate
    epochs=epochs
    batch_size=batch_size

    inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="inputs")
    labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="labels")

    if model ==0:
        pred,_,_,_= rnn_0_fc_layers(inputs_)
    else:
        model ==1:
            pred,_,_,_=rnn_1_fc_layers(inputs_)

    with tf.name_scope('cost'):
        cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels_, pred)
        tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)

    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    with tf.name_scope('eval'):
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.round(pred), tf.int32), labels_)
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))


    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        iteration = 0

        for e in range(epochs):
            state = sess.run(model.initial_state)

            for i1, (x,y) in enumerate(get_batch(train_x, train_y, batch_size), 1):
                feed = {
                    inputs_ : x,
                    labels_ : y[:, None], 
                    keep_prob : 0.5,
                    model.initial_state : state}

                summary, acc, loss, state, _ = sess.run([merged, accuracy, cost, model.final_state, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)

                if iteration%5 == 0:
                    train_acc= []
                    train_acc.append(acc)
                    print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e, epochs),
                         "Iteration: {}".format(iteration),
                         "Accuracy: {}".format(train_acc),
                         "Train Loss: {:.3f}".format(loss))

                if iteration%5 == 0:
                    val_acc = []
                    val_loss= []
                    val_state = sess.run(model.cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32))
                    for x, y in get_batch(val_x, val_y, batch_size):
                        feed = {inputs_ : x,
                               labels_ : y[:, None],
                               keep_prob : 1,
                               model.initial_state : val_state}
                        summary, batch_acc, batch_loss, val_state = sess.run([merged, accuracy, cost, model.final_state], feed_dict=feed)
                        val_acc.append(batch_acc)
                        val_loss.append(batch_loss)
                    print("Val acc: {:.3f}".format(np.mean(val_acc)))
                    print("Val loss: {:.3f}".format(np.mean(val_loss)))                
                iteration += 1
```